# How can I disable pop-up keyboard for edit text in android studio

Tags: java, build.xml

I have chosen a edit text view for calculator but want to disable the pop-up keyboard permanently..how can I simply do that???

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question with minimal example

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attribute of the activity in manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

This will restrict the keyboard during the activity

Comment: @ZerryMirza Which API are you targetting..? This works perfectly for me. If it is causing issues for you try the following:

Add a new Linear Layout to the xml with zero dimesnions and set the following two attributes of the Linear Layout:

`android:focusable=true`
`android:focusableInTouchMode=true`

A little tricky but works.